Eigenvalue and Eigenpair of $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{x}\mathbf{d}^T$(the matrix is disturbed)
Suppose that $\lambda(\mathbf{A})=\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_n\}$ are the eigenvalues for $\mathbf{A}_{n\times n}$, and let $(\lambda_k,\mathbf{x})$ be a particular eigenpair.
Prove for an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{d}_{n\times 1}$, the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{x}\mathbf{d}^T$ agree with those of $\mathbf{A}$ except that $\lambda_k$ is replaced by $\lambda_k+\mathbf{d^T x}$.
I can only prove that Let consider matrix $(\mathbf{A+xd}^T)$
$$
    \mathbf{A+xd}^T\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{Ax+xd}^T\mathbf{x} = \lambda_k \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{xd}^T\mathbf{x} =(\lambda_k+\mathbf{xd}^T)\mathbf{x}
    \neq \lambda_k \mathbf{x}
    $$
So we prove that $\lambda_k$ is replaced by $\lambda_k +\mathbf{d}^T\mathbf{x}$.
So why other eigenvalues have not changed.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

This mainly considers the change of eigenvalues when the matrix is disturbed
